# Detection of Negative Binary

Tags: binary, twos-complement

Today in class my Computing teacher was explaining to us (or attempting to explain) how to write a negative binary number using Two's Complement. My question is this:

How does the end user determine the difference between 11101100 being 236 and -20? I know you can always check the most significant bit but is this always 100% accurate? Is it a convention of negative binary numbers to have the most significant bit indicate the sign?

*Side note*:
Why do we learn binary subtraction when we can just do:

> Convert binary to denary -> subtract denary -> reconvert into binary

Comment: There is lots of good info in the answers, particularly from @jerry. What are you still unclear about?

Comment: What Hvanbrug means is, why haven't you marked your favorite as answer? This gives reputation points to the one who has spent his time for you so you should do this tiny step to appreciate it.

Comment: @hvanbrug and Matt I really appreciate the kind words, but [it doesn't appear that the OP has been on since I expanded my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1590990/kezz101) (prompted by [the OP's questions in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488435/detection-of-negative-binary/16625673#comment23918813_16625673)). Even ignoring that, I think it's definitely fair to wait until the bounty expires to pick an answer. And if the Kezz101 decides not to accept or award the bounty, that's up to him/her (though obviously I'd be curious abouth how I could make my answer better).

Comment: You covered it all, but I fear that it might be info overload. It is hard to say what @Kezz101 is actually after and what he/she understands from what we are saying.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the quality of your answers! They are all brilliant! I've been revising lots for my final 3 exams and SO hasn't really been a priority. :) EDIT: It's probably the best answer I've received on SO...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Question 1:

> "Is it a convention of negative binary numbers to have the most significant bit indicate the sign?"

There are multiple ways to represent negative numbers in binary. The most common is the two's-complement representation that you're learning about. In that system, yes, the highest-order bit will indicate the sign of the number (if 0 is grouped with the positive numbers).

In standard unsigned binary, numbers are represented by sequences of bits in positional notation (for brevity I'll only be using three bits):

> b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>0</sub> = 2<sup>2</sup>b<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup>b<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>0</sup>b<sub>0</sub> = 4b<sub>2</sub> + 2b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>0</sub>
>
> 111<sub>2</sub> = 7<sub>10</sub>
> 110<sub>2</sub> = 6<sub>10</sub>
> 101<sub>2</sub> = 5<sub>10</sub>
> 100<sub>2</sub> = 4<sub>10</sub>
> 011<sub>2</sub> = 3<sub>10</sub>
> 010<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>
> 001<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>
> 000<sub>2</sub> = 0<sub>10</sub>

***Two's-complement***
There are several ways to look at 2s-complement, I think the answer is apparent in all of them. One way to get this system is to take the top half of the unsigned numbers (which all have the high bit set) and move them below zero:

> 011<sub>2</sub> = 3<sub>10</sub>
> 010<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>
> 001<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>
> 000<sub>2</sub> = 0<sub>10</sub>
> **111<sub>2</sub> = -1<sub>10</sub>
>
> 110<sub>2</sub> = -2<sub>10</sub>
>
> 101<sub>2</sub> = -3<sub>10</sub>
>
> 100<sub>2</sub> = -4<sub>10</sub>**

You can clearly see that the high bit indicates the sign. Again, 0 takes up one of the 4 positive representations, which leads to the range not being symmetric: [3, -4] (though sometimes the most negative value is considered special, making the *usable* range symmetric). Equivalently, we can reinterpret the highest-order bit as a negative number:

> b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>0</sub> = **-(2<sup>2</sup>)** b<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup>b<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>0</sup>b<sub>0</sub> = **-4** b<sub>2</sub> + 2b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>0</sub>

Clearly, since the high bit has a bigger weight (in the sense of absolute value) than all the other bits combined, if it's set, the result is negative. If it's not set, all the remaining weights are positive and hence so is the result.

From this definition, we can derive the third interpretation: the commonly known rule that `-a = ~a + 1` (where `-` means arithmetic negation, `~` means bitwise complementation, and we ignore overflow):

> a + ~a = -4b<sub>2</sub> + 2b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>0</sub> + -4(~b<sub>2</sub>) + 2(~b<sub>1</sub>) + ~b<sub>0</sub>
> a + ~a = -4(b<sub>2</sub>+~b<sub>2</sub>) + 2(b<sub>1</sub>+~b<sub>1</sub>) + (b<sub>0</sub>+~b<sub>0</sub>)
> a + ~a = -4(1) + 2(1) + (1)
> a + ~a = -1
> a = -(~a + 1)
> **-a = ~a + 1**

Here, we see that negation flips the high bit, so it indicates the sign of the number. Note that this is not *strictly* true, as the addition with one can flip the high bit back if all the other bits are set. However, this is only the case for 0 and the most negative number (-4<sub>10</sub>, or 100<sub>2</sub>, in this case), both of which remain the same when negated.

The benefit in using 2s-complement is that the same hardware can be used to do signed and unsigned addition. This nice property does not hold for the other negative binary representations that have been used in the past, some of which I'll touch on briefly. Due to this fact, modern CPUs almost always use this representation for integer arithmetic (I'm not aware of any recent commercial counterexamples, but they may be out there). This is why you are learning about it (as opposed to `Convert binary to denary -> subtract denary -> reconvert into binary`): to understand how operations work at the gate level of an ALU.

***One's-complement***
1s-complement is closely related to 2s-complement. Negation is performed by inverting the bits only (no addition of 1). The leading bit still indicates sign, but there are different representations for positive and negative zero. I've never personally come across a real-world use of 1s-complement, but it's of historical interest.

> b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>0</sub> = -3b<sub>2</sub> + 2b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>0</sub>
>
> 011<sub>2</sub> = 3<sub>10</sub>
> 010<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>
> 001<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>
> 000<sub>2</sub> = 0<sub>10</sub>
> 111<sub>2</sub> = -0<sub>10</sub>
> 110<sub>2</sub> = -1<sub>10</sub>
> 101<sub>2</sub> = -2<sub>10</sub>
> 100<sub>2</sub> = -3<sub>10</sub>

***Sign-and-magnitude***
Sign-and-magnitude is closest to how humans normally write negative numbers. The low two bits have the same weight as in the systems above and the high bit has no (additive) weight. Instead, it *only* changes the sign of the result. Here, obviously, the leading bit indicates sign. Like 1s-complement, there are two representations of 0. It is still used today in the mantissa of IEEE floating point numbers (although the exponent sits between the sign and the magnitude).

> b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>0</sub> = **(-1)<sup>b<sub>2</sub></sup>**(2b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>0</sub>)
>
> 0 11 <sub>2</sub> = + 3 <sub>10</sub>
> 0 10 <sub>2</sub> = + 2 <sub>10</sub>
> 0 01 <sub>2</sub> = + 1 <sub>10</sub>
> 0 00 <sub>2</sub> = + 0 <sub>10</sub>
> 1 00 <sub>2</sub> = - 0 <sub>10</sub>
> 1 01 <sub>2</sub> = - 1 <sub>10</sub>
> 1 10 <sub>2</sub> = - 2 <sub>10</sub>
> 1 11 <sub>2</sub> = - 3 <sub>10</sub>

***Excess-n***
Excess-n is really more like a family of systems. All values are shifted up by n (known as the *bias*) and then represented as in the unsigned case. The leading bit *may* indicate the sign if the right bias is chosen, though with different polarity than the above systems (and 0 could be grouped with either the negatives or the positives). This is still used in the exponent of IEEE floating point numbers. For n = 3, the high bit does indicate sign and 0 is grouped with the negative numbers:

> b<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>0</sub> = 4b<sub>2</sub> + 2b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>0</sub> **- n**
>
> 111<sub>2</sub> = 4<sub>10</sub>
> 110<sub>2</sub> = 3<sub>10</sub>
> 101<sub>2</sub> = 2<sub>10</sub>
> 100<sub>2</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>
> 011<sub>2</sub> = 0<sub>10</sub>
> 010<sub>2</sub> = -1<sub>10</sub>
> 001<sub>2</sub> = -2<sub>10</sub>
> 000<sub>2</sub> = -3<sub>10</sub>

***Others***
There are yet other, more esoteric, integer representations such as balanced-ternary, base-negative-2, or (arguably) binary coded decimal (or BCD for short). The reason I say BCD is arguable is that modern processors often still have support for it (though it's not how numbers are represented internally) and many calculators used to be based on it. In these systems, the leading bit (or trit, or base-n digit) may or may not indicate the sign (or may indicate it in some cases but not others).

### Question 2:

> "How does the end user determine the difference between 11101100 being 236 and -20?"

In general there's no way to tell whether a number stored in a register or memory is actually meant to be 2s-complement or unsigned, as pointed out by others. You essentially have to track what's done with it to determine that.

However, if the number is an immediate value stored directly in a machine code instruction, the opcode could indicate whether or not it's signed (depending on the architecture). This may change, for instance, how *overflows* are handled, or whether or not *sign-extension* is performed.

For example, there may be separate "load immediate" and "load signed immediate" instructions that copy an immediate value value into a larger register, the second doing sign-extension and the first not. "Branch" instructions often have a signed immediate to indicate the size of the jump (so that both forward and backwards branches can use a single instruction). There may be different "add immediate" and "add unsigned immediate" instructions that set overflow flags appropriately for the type of addition.

***Sign extension***
Sign extension means copying the high bit to preserve the value of a 2s-complement number. This will produce incorrect results for half the unsigned numbers.

Sign extension not performed:

> 100<sub>2</sub> = 00000100<sub>2</sub>
> Unsigned: 4<sub>10</sub> = 4<sub>10</sub>
> Signed: -4<sub>10</sub> = 4<sub>10</sub>

Sign extension performed:

> 100<sub>2</sub> = 11111100<sub>2</sub>
> Signed: -4<sub>10</sub> = -4<sub>10</sub>
> Unsigned: 4<sub>10</sub> = 252<sub>10</sub>
>
> 001<sub>2</sub> = 00000001<sub>2</sub>
> Signed and unsigned: 1<sub>10</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>

***Overflow***
Adding or subtracting two numbers may give a result that is too big (in an absolute sense) to be correctly represented. Addition of the same two binary sequences may cause overflow for signed numbers but not unsigned (or vice versa).

Signed overflows but unsigned does not:

> 011<sub>2</sub> + 011<sub>2</sub> = 110<sub>2</sub>
> Signed: 3<sub>10</sub>+3<sub>10</sub> = -2<sub>10</sub>
> Unsigned: 3<sub>10</sub>+3<sub>10</sub> = 6<sub>10</sub>

Unsigned overflows but signed does not:

> 111<sub>2</sub> + 010<sub>2</sub> = 001<sub>2</sub>
> Unsigned: 7<sub>10</sub> + 2<sub>10</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>
> Signed: -1<sub>10</sub> + 2<sub>10</sub> = 1<sub>10</sub>

Comment: Brilliant answer! Can you elaborate on what you mean by the 'opcode'? Also I kinda don't know what you are talking about for the last three paragraphs :s am I just really nooby?

Comment: @Kezz101 Thanks, but it's just an overview. **opcode** stands for **operation code**, the part of the instruction that indicates what it does: addition, subtraction, branching, et cetera. The opcodes (and their arguments) are defined by the *instruction set architecture* (or *ISA*). Not understanding the last three paragraphs doesn't mean much, they are uncommon ways of representing negative numbers. You're only likely to run into two of them (sign-and-magnitude and excess-n), and only then in the context of floating point numbers. I'll expand the answer a bit in the next couple of days.

Comment: Ok thanks! Let me know when you do; I'm very interested in Binary at the moment.

Comment: @Kezz101 I updated the answer. I'm not sure if you're automatically notified as the asker, so I'm letting you know as you asked.

Comment: Very thorough. Nice answer

Comment: This should be in classrooms.

Answer (score 4):

1. In two's complement notation, the highest bit *always* indicates the sign.  However, you must know the field width, and you must also know if two's complement notation is being used.  For example, if 11101100 is a 32-bit number, then the most significant bit is 0, so it is +236.  If it is an *unsigned* 8-bit integer, then is +236 because unsigned numbers do not use two's complement notation (only signed numbers do).
2. Adding and subtracting in binary is how the computer does it.  So it is useful to know in order to understand how the computer works.

Answer (score 3):

> How does the end user determine the difference between 11101100 being
>   236 and -20?

The user cannot determine it from the bit pattern alone.  Some context must tell whether this byte is signed or unsigned.  In most programming languages, this context is tracked by keeping track of types.  Thus in C or C++  you have `signed char` and `unsigned char`.   (Plain old `char` could be either one).

There reason that binary subtraction works is that it (like some other operations) happens to be exactly the same thing to the bit pattern even if you got the type "wrong".  One way to think of this is that *(for these operations)* you are doing arithmetic modulo 256, and in that modulus 236 and -20 are actually two names for the same number.

Comment: This is a very dangerous way to look at it. I had a math major working for me once and he said to me that the sign is irrelevant. It is only the magnitude that matters. Although this is technically true sometimes, manipulation of the number can mess you up if you do not have it's actual numerical value in mind. In your case, considering 236 and -20 as the same number will break your code in many cases, such as looping down to -20. You will not get there when you expect to if you have your -20 stored in an unsigned type.

Comment: I've edited my post to repeat that it is only some operations that occur modulo 256.  In modulo 256, these numbers really are the same.  But an 8-bit int is not the same as a moudlo-256 integer: they are just equivalent for some specific operations and that explains those operations work the way they do.

Comment: I have been burned so many times by code that does not care about types the way it should (whether it be my own code or someone else's) that I am now paranoid about it and have become anal about data typing. :)

Comment: @hvanbrug How is this dangerous,it's the truth. If you look at random bits in memory you can't tell if its signed or not.  And technically when the computer is operating purely on 8 bit numbers it is equivalent.  The binary representation is the same and if you print either one out as a signed or unsigned 8 bit int you'll get one or the other.   It's the programmer's responsibility to make sure his types are sufficient to hold the values they operate on.
Question is what do you mean by code that doesn't care about types the way it should?

Comment: @UpAndAdam, please look at the following code (sorry for the bad formatting, it's difficult to format code in a comment).
`char cVal = -20;
unsigned char ucVal = cVal;
int i;
printf( "%d - %d\n\n", cVal, ucVal );
for( i = 3; i >= cVal; --i ) printf( "signed: %d\n", i );
for( i = 3; i >= ucVal; --i ) printf( "unsigned: %d\n", i );`
The first loop is run 23 times. The second loop is not ever run. That is why it is dangerous to not pay attention to the types of your variables. Yes, it is the programmer's responsibility, and the programmer needs to take that responsibility seriously.

Comment: @hvanbrug The second loop isn't run because it shouldn't be.  I would never expect it to run. If you don't turn off all your warnings you'd probably get a compiler warning regarding loss of precision from conversion from signed to unsigned in that assignment.  
Not paying any attention to what you are doing is dangerous period, that's a universal truth, no argument there. But you still haven't explained to me what is dangerous about his explanation; it's correct. What's dangerous is trying to blindly decide what the context should be. Poster never suggested it was safe or tried to.

Comment: I agree with you. What I am saying is dangerous is the statement: "One way to think of this is that (for these operations) you are doing arithmetic modulo 256, and in that modulus 236 and -20 are actually two names for the same number". It is technically correct, and knowing that might help you on occasion, but thinking of it in those terms (they are the same number) has the potential for the programmer to get sloppy. They are NOT the same number, and only appear to behave similarly in some circumstances. (to be continued ...)

Comment: It is more clear when the programmer associates a data type with the binary representation when thinking of a number. The binary bits by themselves do not a number make. You MUST have the data type along with it, as a decoder ring if you will. So, if you have some code similar to my example, but elaborate enough that you don't notice that you made a booboo on the type, you will not get the expected results, and it might take you a while to figure out why. (to be continued ...)

Comment: The best way to prevent bugs in your code is to not put them there in the first place, and the best way to do that is to have a very clear picture in your head of what you are doing. In other words, `11101100` when used as a `signed char` is NEVER the same number as `11101100` when used as an `unsigned char`, EVER. And one should never think of them as the same.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it depends on how you are using it. Almost all modern compilers represent their integer values as two's compliment. It's a convention. If you are writing your code in assembly then you have to pay closer attention to what is in memory or in a register, but in higher level languages the value's data type tells you. If the type is signed then the MSB is the sign bit, otherwise it is not. The data type also tells you how many bits are in the value so you will be able to identify which bit is the MSB. For example, an int8_t is always 8 bits and is signed, whereas a uint8_t is always 8 bits but is unsigned. So long as you know how to identify the data type you know exactly how to interpret the value in memory when you see it represented in binary.